# Agent-set input function returning list error

Tags: function, netlogo

I am trying to create a new function in my model which an agent performs on each of it’s neighbours successively, aggregating the sum as it goes along. For example (return value from neighbour1) + (return value from neighbour2) + (return value from neighbour3)…….n?

However, slightly more complicated, this function consists of two already programmed agent-set inputted functions and in fact looks like this:

Function3:

((function1 [myself neighbour1] * function2 [myself neighbour1]) + (function1 [myself neighbour2] * function2 [myself neighbour2]) + (function1 [myself neighbour3] * function2 [myself neighbour3])……n?))`

I have been trying to implement this in Netlogo using the code:

```
let function3 (sum [function1 myself self] of neighbours) * ( sum [function2 myself self] of neighbours)
```

where neighbours have been defined as:

```
let neighbours turtle-set other turtles in-radius neighbourhood
```

and function1 is:

```
to-report function1 [ agent1 agent2 ]
let w2 square w
report exp (- function2 agent1 agent2 / w2)
```

and function2 is:

```
to-report function2 [ agent1 agent2 ]
report ( (square ([a-rock] of agent1 - [rock] of agent2)) + (square ([a-hip-hop] of agent1 - [hip-hop] of agent2)) )
```

However, whenever I run the model I receive an error stating that:
“* expected input to be a number but got the list [0.16000000000000003 0.5000000000000001] instead. error while turtle 2 running * called by procedure FIND-P called by procedure GO called by Button 'go'”

It seems that my new function3 - instead of performing on each neighbour successively, aggregating the sum as it goes along – actually makes a list of (function1 * [myself AllNeighboursOneByOne]) and tries to add this to another list of (function2 * [myself AllNeighboursOneByOne]). This results in the multiplying list error received as mentioned above. I have been looking into this problem for the last week, reading up, and trying new things in several versions but no luck.

I was just wondering if anyone would be able to advise me on my error, or direct me to some relevant information? Thank you kindly for your time.

Comment: I don't think it's possible for the code you have posted to give that error. I think the problem must be in something you haven't posted, or in some difference between your actual code and what you've posted. Here is my reasoning: it is impossible for `sum` to report a list, because `sum` always reports a number; and the code you posted is of the form `sum ... * sum ...`; so it's impossible that you're doing anything there but multiplying two numbers. Your actual code must be different.

Comment: You can test various hypotheses by inserting print statements, so for example before doing `a * b` insert `print is-number? a` and `print is-number? b`. It should print `true` and `true`. If it doesn't, the problem is upstream, so insert print statements upstream, trying to find the first point in time where the actual values in your program different from what you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Seth's comments.  Bottom line: we have to guess at too much of your code. But here is a guess that runs without error:

```
globals [neighbourhood w]
turtles-own [a-rock rock a-hip-hop hip-hop]

to setup
  ca
  set neighbourhood 3 
  set w 1
  ask patches [sprout 1]
end

to f3test
  setup
  ask turtle 1 [print function3]
end

to-report square [#x]
  report #x * #x
end

to-report function3  ;;turtle proc
  let nbrs other turtles in-radius neighbourhood 
  report (
    (sum [function1 myself self] of nbrs)
    *
    ( sum [function2 myself self] of nbrs)
  )
end

to-report function1 [ agent1 agent2 ]  ;;observer proc
let w2 square w
report exp (- function2 agent1 agent2 / w2)
end

to-report function2 [ agent1 agent2 ]  ;;observer proc
report ( 
  (square ([a-rock] of agent1 - [rock] of agent2)) 
  + 
  (square ([a-hip-hop] of agent1 - [hip-hop] of agent2)) 
)
end
```

Comment: Hello Seth and Alan. Thank you very much for posting your helpful comments. Seth was correct when he told me that the summing would not result in this kind of error. The error was upstream from another function which is almost identical and named similarly, but which did not include 'sum'. Using sum, I no longer received the errors could continue to check other parts of my work.....

Comment: With the modifications from Seth and extremely useful example from Alan I am able to make a model in which.....

Comment: (func1 me & Neigh1) + (func1 me & N2) +  (func1 me & N3)……. Across all neighbours  e.g. 0.4 + 0.7 + 0.3  can be summed (to 1.4) then multiplied the sum of (func2 me & Neigh1) + (func2 me & N2) + (func2 me & N3) (e.g. 0.1 + 0.3 + 0.1 = 0.5) . Ultimately 1.4 * 0.5 = 0.7

Comment: However (and as my poor explanation did not help clarify) this was not my intention. Rather I was hoping to have the (func1 me & Neigh1 * func2 me & Neigh1) e.g. (0.4 * 0.1) and then add this to (func1 me & N2) * (func2 me & N2) e.g. (0.7 * 0.3) and then add this to (func1 me & N3) * (func2 me & N3) e.g. (0.3 * 0.1) which would ultimately give 0.04 + 0.21 + 0.003 = 0.253

Comment: Over the last few days I have been working on how to achieve such, and have read that using Array would possibly be a way forward. Therefore I have now achieved this result using the following code:

Comment: let fun1 array:from-list [func1 myself self] of neighbours
  let fun2 array:from-list [func2 myself self] of neighbours
  let result[] let sumresult []
  
  
  foreach indices fun1 [
    set result lput (array:item fun1 ? * array:item fun2 ?) result 
    set sumresult sum result
  ]